# Call an Activity method from inside adapter?

Tags: android

I have a custom Adapter that has a click Listener on the ListView image.

This code is inside the Adapter GetView:

```
holder.iconImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

          //code to do stuff when the image is clicked
}
```

My images in the listview consist of images of folders (to represent a folder) and actual images.

So if the user clicks on a folder image, I want to be able to call a method called "moveDownFolder" in ActivityA.

I'm not sure if this can be done inside of the Adapter?

[EDIT] Basically in ActivityA I have a Click Listener on the custom ListView, so if they click on the text in the custom ListView, it moves down a folder (if it is a folder).

But they can click on an **image** in the ListView, it opens the image in a new activity.  BUT if they click on the folder icon in the listview (which is an image of course in the ImageView) - I want the code to move down a folder, instead of trying to open the image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I Recommending on using interface as listener.

For example:

1, create your interface:

```
public interface MyListener {

void folderClicked();
}
```

2, Let your ActivityA to implement this Interface like this:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity implements MyListener
```

3, you will have to auto overide the method folderClicked it will look like this:

```
@Override
protected void folderClicked() {
  // Do your stuff here.

}
```

4, send the activity listener to the adapter with constructor like this:

```
MyAdpater adapter = new MyAdpater(ActivityA.this);
```

5, in your adapter class your code should be like this :

```
public class TimeLineAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private MyListener mListener;


public TimeLineAdapter(MyListener listener) {
    super();

    mListener = listener;


}

holder.iconImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         mListener.onFolderClicked()
      //code to do stuff when the image is clicked
 }
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this.  Is there any easy way to tell if the user has clicked on a folder image (it is a drawable called folder.png). So if they click on the folder then I can call movedownfolder?

Comment: Yes, are you using objects in your adapter? You can always get the clicked position and then get the item position with the folder details.

Comment: yeah I am, I have the clicked position, but I want to know if it is a folder that was clicked.  Specifically, is there any way to check if the image at that position is a drawable?

Comment: im not sure what you asking for, but if the user clicked on the imageView in lets say row 5, isnt it mean he clicked the folder picture?

Comment: the list view has 'proper' images, and folder images.  If they click on a folder image I want to "movedownfolder".  Ideally lookign for something like this: images.get(position) ==  Bitmap(R.drawable.dbfolder);

Comment: Oh, there no such method that can equals drawable. you will have to think on something smarter. like give a boolean inside each object lets say isFolder = true; then check it on the onClick method.

Comment: Ok I'll mark your answer as correct as I think it will work.  but one last question, if they click on the folder icon, is there a way to simulate the ListView on click Listener in ActivityA?

Comment: Yes, you can use the listView function onItemClickListener like this:  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                
            }
        });  To get the item clicked when your listView.

Comment: I need to pass an int position from the Interface to ActivityA. public void folderClicked(int position)  - but when calling the interface in the adapter like this mListener.folderClicked(position); -- I'm getting a null pointer exception?  The position does have a value..

Comment: could you change your example to pass an int position, to see if it is the same as what I have?  Note that I already had a constructor in my Adapter, but now I have two, a new one I added for the Interface..

Comment: First, change your method in interface class to void folderClicked(int position); second, add the int position to overrided method in your activity. third, when you call this method just pass the row position

Comment: I've asked another question as I'm getting anull pointerhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273906/interface-use-in-adapter

Comment: perhaps you will be able to answer as its based on the code you provided.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23273906/interface-use-in-adapter

Comment: i will help you there then.

Comment: Thank you this is the proper code to change textview from adapter to activity

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done , just make your function as follows `static public moveDownFolder()` . You need to be sure that activity is created. to call that function from Adapter just simply do : `YourActivity.moveDownFolder()`

Answer (score 1):

If the adapter is an inner class of ActivityA, try:

```
ActivityA.this.moveDownFolder();
```

Comment: I get this: ActivityA is not an enclosing class