# Interface use in Adapter

Tags: android

I have a custom adapter which is using an Interface.  Here are the constructors, please let me know if this is wrong:

```
  public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> images, ArrayList folderName, ArrayList<Boolean> isFolder, FolderClickListener listener){

        this.context = c;
        this.images = images;
        this.folderName = folderName;
        this.isFolder=isFolder;
       checkBoxState=new boolean[images.size()];
        //imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        mListener = listener;

    }
```

Then in my `GetView` in the adapter, I call the interface like this:

```
 mListener.folderClicked(position); //Fails with null pointer exception
```

Here is my Interface:

```
public interface FolderClickListener {

    void folderClicked(int position);

}
```

I then have a method in my MainActivity which implements the Interface:

```
@Override
    public void folderClicked(int position) {

//do stuff in here
}
```

Any ideas why I am getting the null pointer exception?
  EDIT: Here is my adapter in MainActivity, how can I pass the interface to this?

```
adapter = new ImageAdapter(TextDropboxActivity.this, pix, paths, folders);
            lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code you are not using the constructor as it should be.

First, make sure your TextDropboxActivity Implement the listener. if yes you will see the override method.

Second, your new adapter should look like this:

```
adapter = new ImageAdapter(TextDropboxActivity.this, pix, paths, folders,TextDropboxActivity.this);
        lstView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

your adapter constructor code:

```
public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> images, ArrayList folderName, ArrayList<Boolean> isFolder,    FolderClickListener listener){

    this.context = c;
    this.images = images;
    this.folderName = folderName;
    this.isFolder=isFolder;
   checkBoxState=new boolean[images.size()];
    //imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    mListener = listener;

}
```

The first TextDropboxActivity.this is the context, and the second one like in my example is the listener.

Also make sure you calling

```
mListener.folderClicked(position);
```

only after button clicked. you can also try sending hard coded value like

```
 mListener.folderClicked(1);
```

And log what you get in the activity code to check if everything is ok.
For example:

```
@Override
public void folderClicked(int position) {

//do stuff in here
Log.i("test",""+position);
}
```

If its work, listener working well and the problem is with how are you sending the row position.

Comment: Thanks - this worked fine, I did not know that I had to pass in TextDropboxActivity.this as the Listener.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Although out of curiosity.  In my adapter code I only call mListener.folderClicked(position); if it is a folder using an if...else.  But when I click on an image, the activity code is still called (I used a Toast to test).  So it gets called if you click on a folder icon OR an image icon...

Comment: so is it ok now or you still more help?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not setting the listener. You have *two* constructors, and only one of them sets the listener. You should have just one constructor that also accepts a listener, and throws an exception if it's null.

Comment: How can you pass the listener it when I bind my adapter in my MainActivity:                                                                                                                        adapter = new ImageAdapter(TextDropboxActivity.this, pix, paths);
            lstView.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: Pass `this` - as your activity implements the interface.

Comment: or simply add a method setListener(listener) to your adapter class.

Comment: passing this is not working,  says it expects a Listener, not a MainActivity.LoadFolders

Comment: could you provide answer using the code in my main post?

Comment: Oooh, you forgot to add `implements FolderClickListener` to your activity class.

Comment: I already have the implements FolderClickListener.  Does it matter that my adapter is bound in the PostExecute of an AyncTask?  it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I have modified my code to use one constructor in the image adapter.  But from my activity, how do I pass in the FolderClickListener??

Comment: Use `FolderClickListener.this`, your activity implements the interface, right?